# Page menu with one image link instead of page title?

Tags: menus

I have the following code generated by wordpress for my nav1:

```
<div id="nav1">
<ul class="menusm">
    <li class="page_item page-item-6"><a title="Inicio" href="http://localhost/road/" class="top_level">Inicio</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-11"><a title="Quienes Somos" href="http://localhost/road/quienes-somos" class="top_level">Quienes Somos</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-13"><a title="Servicios" href="http://localhost/road/servicios" class="top_level">Servicios</a>
        <ul class="children" style="display: none;">
            <li class="page_item page-item-25"><a title="Inteligencia" href="http://localhost/road/servicios/inteligencia" class="">Inteligencia</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-27"><a title="Personal, Equipos, Armamentos" href="http://localhost/road/servicios/personal-equipos-armamentos" class="">Personal, Equipos, Armamentos</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-22"><a title="Seguridad Operativa" href="http://localhost/road/servicios/seguridad-operativa" class="">Seguridad Operativa</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-17"><a title="Contacto" href="http://localhost/road/contacto" class="top_level">Contacto</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-37 current_page_item"><a title="Cotice su stand en ferias" href="http://localhost/road/pedir-cotizacion" class="top_level">Cotice su stand en ferias</a></li>
</ul><div class="clr"></div>
```

And I would like the last `<li>` tag under the title of "Cotice su stand en ferias" to use a button instead of text as the rest of the `<li>`'s. Is there a way to accomplish this without having to completely remove that item and placing a button next to the `#nav1`?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Edit: got it.

```
#nav1 ul li:last-child {background: url(images/cotizacion-icono.jpg) no-repeat scroll;}
```

Comment: You mean an image that you have, that happens to look like a button, or a button like `<input type="button"/>`? (Use `@Jan` when you reply in a comment and I get a notification)

Comment: If you found the solution yourself you can also add it as an answer, you don't have to edit the question for that. (Perhaps you have to wait a day before you can do that as a new user, to prevent people from gaming the system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jQuery Solution**

if you're using jQuery you can use:

`var $li = jQuery('ul > li:last-child','#nav1');`

to select your last menu child.

Then after you select it you can chain it with another function:

`$li.wrapInner('<input type="button" value="My Button!">');`

Then all together:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   // Cache your selection
   var $li = jQuery('ul > li:last-child','#nav1');
   // Replace it with your button
   $li.wrapInner('<input type="button" value="My Button!">');
});
```

**Pure CSS Solution**

Setup your dropdown navigation:

PHP in the template:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title',
    'menu_class'  => 'menu',
    'include'     => '',
    'exclude'     => '',
    'echo'        => true,
    'show_home'   => false,
    'link_before' => '<span>', // Wrap your span here
    'link_after'  => '</span>' ); // close it with a span too
?>
```

Comment: Well Chris, what I don't know is how to select that particular li, as something like this won't work: .page-item-37 li {background: url(images/icono.jpg) no-repeat scroll;}

Comment: With jQuery right? If yes. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Can't this be done with pure css?

Comment: Yes. I would change your menu output to wrap each item span and then add a button.

Comment: I added the menu setup as to how to above. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the new custom navigation menu functionality added in WordPress 3.0, you can use straight HTML in the *Navigation label* box. So it's no problem to write the image code there instead of the regular title.

[image: Menu admin page with HTML code]

[image: Front page menu with image]

Comment: I'm not doing this with categories but pages. Could I somehow try to apply this to custom fields?

Comment: sorry @jan I had not seen the message earlier

Comment: @user5057: I could have known it by looking closer at your example output. No problem, I clarified my answer to make it clearer for others with the same problem. It seems the answer from Chris helped you out? You can then click the checkmark next to that answer to [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you could do [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDGmJ/1/):

```
$('#nav1').find('> ul > li:last-child a').wrapInner('<button/>');
```

However, going for [pure CSS](http://mezzoblue.com/archives/2008/09/17/anchor_butto/) seems like the cleaner way to go. Using `border-radius` you can easily apply a button look to a regular anchor.

Comment: I don't need a button look but to use an image that I was sent by the web's owner